# Replace string keys with array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6

i have the below code:

```
const chaine  =  'lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}}..." ;
```

i need replace all {{name}} with the array elements like this

```
cont list  = ['java', 'regex']
```

so the expected result is

```
lorem java lorem lorem regex...
```

Note:

- {{name}} numbers in string is variable
- array element length is **variable** , we can have 1..N

thanks

Comment: `{{name}} numbers in string is variable`  What do you mean here, what numbers are you talking about?.

Comment: just split by your needle and replace it using map.

Comment: @Keith, for this example i have two   {{name}},  in  an other example i have  3 {{name}}  example 'lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}} lorem {{name}}..." . i need a generic solution

Comment: if the {{variable}} is `variable` then this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522292/how-to-use-template-literals-for-cms/56522861#56522861

Comment: What happens if you have a templte of `one {{name}} two {{name}} three {{name}}` but only have `["alpha", "beta"]`? Or if the array contains `["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look for the replacement values and get the item from `list`.

```js
var string = 'lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}}...',
    list = ['java', 'regex'],
    result = string.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/g, (i => _ => list[i++])(0));

console.log(result);
```

A bit more advanced version by taking an object and a property for every propery for the index.

```js
var string = 'lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}}, {{foo}}...',
    replacements = { name: ['java', 'regex'], foo: ['bar'] },
    result = string.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/g, (_, key) => {
        if (!(key in replacements)) return key;
        replacements['_' + key] = replacements['_' + key] || 0;
        return replacements[key][replacements['_' + key]++];
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Oh. The first example is just fantastic. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Could also `shift` from the list instead of the IIFE if you wanted (though that'll mutate if you don't copy it first, ofc) `_ => list.shift()`

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work using `.replace()`.
Demo:

```js
const chaine  =  "lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}}..." ;
const list  = ['java', 'regex'];
var result = chaine.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/g, function(text) {
  return list.shift();
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const chaine = 'lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}}...';
const list = ['java', 'regex'];

const textWithEverythingReplaced = list.reduce((textWithReplacedValues, wordToReplaceItWith) => {
  return textWithReplacedValues.replace("{{name}}", wordToReplaceItWith)
}, chaine);

console.log(textWithEverythingReplaced);
```

---

### Disclaimer

As much as this code can work, the algorithm is not robust. It will break when you have more `{{name}}` than you have `replacers`.

Unless you can validate the fact that there are equal number of `{{name}}` as there are `list.length`, you should be alright.

Answer (score 1):

Seen as you want it to be generic, it might also make sense to make into a re-usable function.  Below is an example.

```js
const repFn = (str, arr) => {
  let i = 0;
  return str.replace(/{{name}}/g, x =>arr[i ++]);
}

const chaine  =  "lorem {{name}} lorem lorem {{name}}..." ;
const list  = ['java', 'regex'];



console.log(repFn(chaine, list));
console.log(
  repFn("{{name}}, a few {{name}} can {{name}} up the {{name}} of a thousand",
    ["Sometimes", "words", "sum", "wisdom"]
));
```